# $.post refreshes the page but $.ajax prevents refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have this `form`:

```
<form id="frmValidate" action="Controller/Action" novalidate>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="names"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form"/>
</form>
```

and I have **[`jquery validation`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)** plugin applied for the above `form` as below:

```
$("#frmValidate").validate({
    rules: {
        names: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    messages:{
        names:{
            required:'Name is required',
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!")
        }
    },
    errorClass:'invalid',
    submitHandler:function(form){
        var url=$(form).attr('action');
        var formData=new FormData($("#frmValidate"));
        $.post(url,formData,function(){
            alert('submit Done'); 
        });
    }
});
```

When I use `$.post` which is shorthand for `$.ajax - POST`, it refreshes the page, but if I use `$.ajax` with type `Post`, as below:

```
submitHandler:function(form){
    var url=$(form).attr('action');
    var formData=new FormData($("#frmValidate"));
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error:function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

This doesn't **refresh** the page and gets the response successfully unlike `$.post`. I prefer shorthand method since it is simple and elegant. But because of the above problem, I am not able to use it.

> Is there any way to prevent the default action of the `form` in
>   `submitHandler`? or any information on why `$.post` doesn't prevent page from getting refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `FormData();` and this only can be used with `xmlHttpRequest` only and `$.post()` doesn't have it but `$.ajax()` has. That's why `$.ajax()` is working and the shorthand `$.post()` is not working.

```
submitHandler:function(form){
    var url=$(form).attr('action');
    var formData=$("#frmValidate").serialize(); // instead serialize it.
    $.post(url,formData,function(){
        alert('submit Done'); 
    });
}
```

One more thing i want to add that if you are using `FormData()` then make sure to pass the `form` not the jQuery object:

```
var formData=new FormData($("#frmValidate")[0]);
```

and if you are trying to upload a file via ajax then i guess you know to set these options to `false`:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

Comment: Thank you Jai, Let me try this and will get back if I face any problem, but few doubts here, So with `FormData` there is no way I can use `$.post` right? Also using `serialize` can I obtain `model` in `controller`, for ex: `public JsonResult MyAction(MyModelClass model)`? does `model` here gets filled with serialize, [hoping you know `asp.net MVC`]. With `FormData`, I will get this,as I have tested the same..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao _asp.net_.....:(, never worked with this technology but i have java environment. if that is the case then you can go with `FormData()` in conjunction with `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Oh, ok.. no probs.. I will test it myself.. Give me some moments and I'll let you know.. :)

Comment: Perfect Jai.. Works with `serialize` not with `FormData`.. Thanks for your time and help.. :)

Comment: I have one doubt here.. Can I ask?

Comment: `$("#frmValidate")[0]` is equivalent to `$("#frmValidate")` right? since `id` will always be unique and it will return single `element` unlike `$(".frmValidate")[0]`, i.e. `form` referred with `classname`, which can return array of `elements`? Do we need `[0]` there?

Comment: Yes we need to have a `[0]` if we have to convert a jQuery object to a dom node and it just returns only a single element. Although ids are unique per element and it always returns a single element but in this case we have to put `[0]` or a method of jQuery `.get(0)` this also does the same.

Comment: Oh like that.. Thanks for the details.. :) Sorry for disturbing again.. :) Have a nice time.. :)